# How to fetch value from parent table using foreign key in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have face problem with retriving value from parent table using foreign key.

I am using two table,

1) Question Table

2) Answer Table

In Question Table fields is,`questionId` , `question` and `requiredTime`.
In Answer Table fields is, `answerId` , `answer` and `questionId`(Foreign Key which is refer from Question Table)

My Problem is,
In Question Table how to fetch value for questionId and insert into Answer table?

For one Question have 4 Answer means 4 options as per Question.

```
//Create Table Question
    public static final String CREATE_QUESTION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_QUESTION
            + " ( "
            + KEY_QUESTION_ID
            + " INTEGER primary key not null , "
            + KEY_QUESTION
            + " text not null , "
            + KEY_TIME_REQUIRED + " text " + ");";


   //Create Table Answer
    public static final String CREATE_ANSWER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_ANSWER
            + " ( "
            + KEY_ANSWER_ID
            + " INTEGER primary key not null , "
            + KEY_ANSWER
            + " text , "
            + KEY_QUESTION_ID
            + " INTEGER ,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_QUESTION_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_QUESTION + " (" + KEY_QUESTION_ID + "));";


In Code,

                    for (int i = 0; i < arr_question_id.size(); i++) {

                            item_bean.setTimeRequired(arr_time_required.get(i));
                            item_bean.setQuestionId(arr_question_id.get(i));
                            item_bean.setQuestion(arr_question.get(i));

                            dbAdapter.openForWrite();
                            dbAdapter.insertQuestion(Integer.parseInt(arr_question_id.get(i)), arr_question.get(i), arr_time_required.get(i));
                            dbAdapter.close();
                        }


                        for (int j = 0; j < arr_answer_id.size(); j++) {
                            item_bean.setAnswerId(arr_answer_id.get(j));
                            item_bean.setAnswer(arr_answer.get(j));
                            item_bean.setCorrect(arr_correct.get(j));

                            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!1 Integer.parseInt(arr_question_id.get(j)=====" + json_object_question.getString("questionID"));

                            dbAdapter.openForWrite();
                            dbAdapter.insertAnswer(Integer.parseInt(arr_answer_id.get(j)), arr_answer.get(j), Integer.parseInt(json_object_question.getString("questionID")));
                            dbAdapter.close();
                        }

Problem with below Line,
 dbAdapter.insertAnswer(Integer.parseInt(arr_answer_id.get(j)), arr_answer.get(j), Integer.parseInt(json_object_question.getString("questionID")));

For Question Id,For one Question loop repeat 4 times.


Table Question
***************
questionId  question                    timeRequired
1           What is your Name?          10
2           What is your pets Name?     10
3           What is your native?        10  
etc.

Table Answer
***********
answerId       answer       questionId
101            Neha         1
102            Sneha        1
103            Meeta        1
104            Mamata       1

105            Meetu        2
106            Keenu        2
107            Teenu        2
108            Nehu         2

etc.
```

I m not able to fetching value for questionId for Table Answer.
Please Help me.
I am waiting for your response and your suggestion.
Please Suggest Me.
Thanks.
Reena

Comment: May be i think you not need to use Reference of foreign key in your Answer table. So i suggest you to remove that reference of foreign key and while you adding answer give where condition for `Question ID` so it will take it.

Comment: @jaydroider How to implemet. i take arraylist and all value store it and arraylist store into sqlite database for question table  and answer table

Comment: Remove that reference of foreign key from `Answer Table`. just keep it `integer` only in answer table and while you adding data in answer table give where condition for Question ID.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had done everything, it is just a matter of select query from your answers table with the questionId that you want:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

String[] columns = new String[] { "answer" }    
String where = KEY_QUESTION_ID + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { questionId + "" };

Cursor c = db.query(
    TABLE_ANSWER /* table */,
    columns /* columns */,
    where /* where or selection */,
    whereArgs /* selectionArgs i.e. value to replace ? */,
    null /* groupBy */,
    null /* having */,
    null /* orderBy */
);
```

Comment: But I want to inserting record into Answer Table

Comment: your answer table should have it's own PK, or have a combine PK with questions table for example (row+quetionId), this is the way you can find answer record and do insertion.

Comment: if I didn't get your question, please explain a little more what you are about to insert and explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can get required result using joins or creating views. It depends on your need. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

You should keep that foreign key constrains otherwise it does not make sense why would you answer if there is no question?